# Small caps in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

Is there a way in Java Swing to show text in small caps (small capitals)?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps

I have loaded a custom font which supports small caps via Font.createFont(). The text should be rendered somehow in small caps. Is this possible in JLabel, JTextPane or some other component?

Comment: Sure it is possible.  What have you tried?  Where is your code?

Comment: In the small cap font I have, lower-case is small cap and upper case is normal cap. Isn't your font the same as this? If so, it is a matter of making the font accessible as a resource, and specifying it as the font.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. It's in the font. When you select a font in a text processor and choose different styles like italic, bold or small caps in that case, it appears as one font with different styles. But they are actually all individual fonts of the same "typeface".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font
So I just took the correct font file for my small caps font and loaded it with Font.createFont().

Answer (score 1):

You can try that, it works : (I get the font here for test : http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Uncategorized/28374/Tahoma_Small_Cap.aspx)

```
String labelText ="Dfd";
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(labelText);
Font g=null;
Font g2=null;
try {
        InputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/alain/Bureau/tahomscb/tahomscb.ttf"));
        g = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
        g2 = g.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("font not loaded.");
    }
    lbl.setFont(g2);
    this.add(lbl);  //this is the parent component
```